# Are the laws of muktzeh biblical or rabbinic

Tags: halacha, derabanan, muktzeh, deorayta, orach-chaim

Are the laws prohibiting handling muktzeh on Shabbat considered biblical (from the Torah) or rabbinic? The reason it matters is because of the rule in Halacha, Safek Derabbanan Lekula vs Safek d’oraita lechumrah.

Sources for this please.

Comment: https://ph.yhb.org.il/plus/01-23-01/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mukktzeh is *d'rabbanan*.

R Daniel Braude writes (Learn Shabbos, p. 442)

> **There is a Rabbinic prohibition** to handle items that are *muktzeh* on
> Shabbat

He spells out some of the reasons the Sages enacted these laws, e.g., to ensure Shabbat remains a day of rest and that we don't use "weekday objects" (Rambam), to prevent people from carrying these items in forbidden areas (Raavad), to prevent us from doing forbidden work with items that likely would lead to do so.

R Eliezer Melamed [writes](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/category/01/01-23/) similarly

> **The Sages prohibited** moving things that are not fitting for Shabbat
> and that one puts out of his mind

Comment: Possibly according to Rashi (Beitzah 2b) *using* *muktzah* is *de'oraysah*.

Comment: Yes as well as on 26b but Tosfos and many other Rishonim disagree